# Access multiple characters using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, string, square-bracket

I'm returning the 2nd, 3rd and 5th numbers in the string `'123456'` by using

```
function returnSome(numbers) {
  return numbers[1] + numbers[2] + numbers[4]
}

returnSome('123456'); //2, 3, 5
```

Simple enough right? What I'm wondering is whether there is a shorter way to write that out? something like numbers[1][2][4]?

I can't seem to find an answer online! (It may well be that I just don't know the correct terminology!)

Comment: [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is useful for *contiguous* parts of a string, but otherwise what you've got is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Pointy This seems crazy! what if I have a string of a thousand numbers and want to extract 20 specific ones in a noncontinuous order?

Comment: For sequential characters you could use `slice()`, `substr()`, `substring()` et al, but for single isolated characters you're already using what's probably the most convenient / readable method.

Comment: no, `numbers[1][2][4]` wouldn't work, because that is saying, in effect, "return the 4th element of the second element of the first element of numbers".  but since numbers is a string, and not an array of arrays of arrays, nothing would be returned.

Comment: "what if I have a string of a thousand numbers and want to extract 20 specific ones"  That's not really a common enough task to need its own built-in language construct.

Comment: @daggett put the indexes of the values in an array and write an iterative function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really shorter, but you could use an array of indices and map that to the strings characters, then join them to a new string:

```
[1, 2, 4].map(i => numbers[i]).join("")
```

> something like numbers[1][2][4]?

We can get quite close with currying:

```
const wrap = (str, res = "") => index => index + 1 ? wrap(str, res + str[index]) : res;

wrap(numbers)(1)(2)(4)()
```

Comment: Ah this is very tidy! It would also be practical if I were extracting 20 numbers for instance. How would I modify this if I wanted the numbers in an array? So let's say the result is `('23', '5')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the indices you want into a string that you iterate over and pull out from the array you pass in.

```
let returnSome = (numbers, sections) => sections.split("").map(i => +numbers[i]);
```

```js
let returnSome = (numbers, sections) => sections.split("").map(i => +numbers[i]);

console.log( returnSome('123456', '124') ); //2, 3, 5
```